# Why can't I find my polymorphic function is dba_procedures

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_nvl
AS

    FUNCTION defaultNVL (tab IN TABLE)
        RETURN TABLE
        PIPELINED ROW POLYMORPHIC USING pkg_nvl;


    FUNCTION describe (tab IN OUT dbms_tf.table_t)
        RETURN dbms_tf.describe_t;

    PROCEDURE fetch_rows;
END pkg_nvl;
```

I've defined the function defaultNVL is pkg_NVL. It's a polymorphic table function. But when  I search the function in dba_procedures althougth I find it, it's not marked as polymorphic.

```
 select polymorphic  from dba_procedures where  and object_name like '%NVL%';
```

> NULL

why?

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b1c364c6c9e7cd2c6cb593c007ad049b) (In dbfiddle, I've changed dba_procedures by user_procedures because this table doesn't exist)

Comment: Because polymorphic function is declared as `return table pipelined [row|table] polymorphic using <pkg>`, but a package is an implementation, not a function itself. Based on your sample: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1a33eae3f6ada50d1590f387a2f48444

Comment: But seems that package polymorphic function is not registered in `*_procedures` at all, which is confusing.